# What is Causing the Incorrect Syntax near SELECT error?

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting an incorrect syntax error near Select in this query. The goal here is to delete the rows in alohaftplog in batches of 1000.

```
DECLARE @Batch INT = 1000
DECLARE @DateLimit DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), GETDATE() - 30, 101)
DECLARE @Cnt INT = 0

SET @Cnt = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit 

WHILE @Cnt > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(@Batch) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit
    SET @Cnt = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @Cnt = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit
```

needs to be:

```
SET @Cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit)
```

OR:

```
SELECT @Cnt = COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @Cnt = COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimi
```

Comment: Although you are right... When answering, please give some context on why your answer is correct and show OP where they need to correct their work to not produce any errors. Keep posting answers!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need a set of parenthesis.

```
SET @Cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AlohaFtpLog WHERE DATE < @DateLimit)
```